# Strange operator of $\vec F(\vec r) = Ae^{i(\vec k \vec r - \omega t)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I have an equation $\vec F(\vec r) = Ae^{i(\vec k \vec r - \omega t)}$ and I should calculate [image] (for a better ilustration a picture). That little square is probably some differential operator but I don't know which. I have already calculated a divergence and a curl of $\vec F(\vec r)$ but I have no idea what to do with that square.

Comment: It's the laplacian. Divergence of gradient.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I thought Laplacian is $\Delta$

Comment: It's not going to be fun to calculate it anyway.

Comment: Sorry! It's 4- laplacian. It allows you to write the wave equation as homogeneous.

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably the d'Alembert operator, which is defined as:
$$\square F = \frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial z^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial t^2}$$
Or, according to some people's conventions, 
$$\square F = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial z^2}$$